# ember.js: Why does the on-input event not work?

Tags: ember.js, event-handling, action

Following the example of the ember.js 2.3.0 guide, 
[EMBER.TEMPLATES.HELPERS CLASS](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_input)

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    // Usage {{input on-input=(action (action 'setName' model) value="target.value")}}
    setName(model, name) {
      model.set('name', name);
    }
  }
});
```

I write my code as follows:

**template.hbs**

```
<div>
{{input type='text' id='Txt01' value='firstName'
  on-input=(action "onInput")
  key-press=(action "onKeyPress")
  key-down=(action "onKeyDown")
  key-up=(action "onKeyUp")
  change=(action "onChange")}}
</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    onKeyPress() {
      console.log('Text-Key-Pressed');
    },
    onKeyDown() {
      console.log('Text-Key-Down');
    },
    onKeyUp() {
      console.log('Text-Key-Up');
    },
    onInput() {
      var value = Ember.$('#Txt01').val();
      console.log('onInput:' + value);
    },
    onChange() {
      var value = Ember.$('#Txt01').val();
      console.log('onInput:' + value);
    }
  }
});
```

Run the code, the logs are

```
Text-Key-Down
Text-Key-Pressed
Text-Key-Up
```

Both oninput event and change event do not work when the value of input is changed.

I just want to achieve the following functions with ember.js.

```
<input type="text" id="text1" value="hello!">
document.getElementById('text1').addEventListener('input', function(){
  var temp = $('#text1').val();
  console.log('Text1: ' + temp);
}, false);

$('#text1').bind('input propertychange', function() {
  var temp = $('#text1').val();
  console.log('Text1: ' + temp);
});
```

Any hints will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The event name that should be used in ember is **'input'** instead of **'on-input'**.

Check [https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/components/handling-events/](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/components/handling-events/#toc_event-names) for the list of events supported by ember components.

Sample Component

```
{{textarea
  value=value
  input=(action "valChange")}}
```

***valChange*** action will be called when **oninput** event is fired.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_input

The helper allows some user events to send actions.

- `enter`
- `insert-newline`
- `escape-press`
- `focus-in`
- `focus-out`
- `key-press`
- `key-up`

A computed property, or observer on the property bound to your input would fire any time it changed.  My answer would really depend on your end goal of what you want to happen when it changes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My end goal is to catch the [oninput](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp) event of  <input type='text'> and the change event of <input type='file'> with ember.js. these events can be catched with jQuery or normal javascript.

Comment: I'll try to use the computed property or observer. Kingpin2k, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

June of 2019:

There are 2 ways of writing it

1. Using `{{input}}` component provided by Ember

Check out why Ember has an `input` component built-in the Ember Core

Stef & Rob: do we still need the built-in Input component? - YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0Rl6o9wLX0&feature=youtu.be

You can write as

```
{{input value="hello world" input=(action "inputActionEventTrigger")}}
```

A list of events are here https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.4.0/components/handling-events/#toc_event-names

2. You can write in the classic html element `input`

```
<input value="helloworld" oninput={{action "inputActionEventTrigger"}}/>
```

Reference from w3cschool: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp

I hope it helps. Thank you.